# Backbone and underscore - templating a simple view

Tags: javascript, templates, dom, backbone.js, underscore.js

I'm not having much luck with my first templated view in Backbone and underscore.

I get a 'players is not defined error' from Underscore library.

This is my Model:

```
define([
    'domLib',
    'underscore',
    'backbone',
    'router'
    ],
    function($, _, Backbone, Router) {

        var PlayerModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
            defaults: {
                username: '',
                rank: 0,
                score: 0
            }
        });

        return PlayerModel;

});
```

This is my collection:

```
define([
    'domLib',
    'underscore',
    'backbone',
    'router',
    'model/player'
    ],
    function($, _, Backbone, Router, PlayerModel) {

        var LeaderboardCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
            model: PlayerModel,
            url: '/hyc-web/leaderBoard/topOverall?count=5'
        });

        return LeaderboardCollection;
});
```

The associated view:

```
define([
    'domLib',
    'underscore',
    'backbone',
    'router',
    'collection/leaderboard',
    'text!template/leaderboard.html'
    ],
    function($, _, Backbone, Router, LeaderboardCollection, LeaderboardTemplate) {

        var LeaderboardView = Backbone.View.extend({
            el: '#leaderboard',
            template: _.template(LeaderboardTemplate),
            initialize: function(){
                this.collection = new LeaderboardCollection();              
                this.collection.on('reset', this.render, this); 
                this.collection.fetch();                                        
            },
            render: function(){         
                console.log(this.collection.models);
                this.$el.html(this.template, {players: this.collection.models});
            }
        });

        return LeaderboardView;
});
```

And the template itself:

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>                             
        <tr>
            <td>Rank</td>
            <td>Player</td>
            <td>Score</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tfoot>
        <!-- Logged in user details here -->
    </tfoot>
    <tbody>
        <% _.each(players, function(player){ %>
            <tr>
                <td><%= player.rank %></td>
                <td><%= player.username %></td>
                <td><%= player.highScore %></td>
            </tr>           
        <% }); %>                                   
    </tbody>
</table>
```

It was all going so well until i tried wiring up to the actual data service layer.  I cannot see why this is not templating the JSON array?

Comment: `this.$el.html(this.template, {players: this.collection.models});` is it a typo? Cause it seems to me you're not evaluating the template here.

Comment: Ok so i changed my view to this:     var compiledTemplate = _.template(LeaderboardTemplate, {players: this.collection.models});
    this.$el.html(compiledTemplate);

Comment: But it does not appear to iterate over the array?

Comment: did you try <%= player.get('rank') %>?  If that doesn't work, I use [this](http://www.wiredprairie.us/blog/index.php/archives/1837) simple trick to debug underscore templates. (And it will work with any browser that has a script debugger)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want your render method to look more like:

```
render: function() {
  this.$el.html(this.template({ players: this.collection.toJSON() });
}
```

You need to pass the data context through your view's template() function, not the jQuery html() function.  Also, you want to convert the collection to JSON using collection.toJSON() instead of passing in a raw array of models using collection.models.

Comment: This is returning the same result as the previous comment regarding the pre-compiled template so a step in the right direction but still not getting any data just the table header.

Comment: also if i log this.collection.toJSON() there are no child objects in the array?

Comment: Maybe take a look at the network request in the browser dev tools to see what the data coming from the server looks like when fetching the collection.

Answer (score 0):

After some digging around in the docs i came up with this:

```
define([
    'domLib',
    'underscore',
    'backbone',
    'router',
    'collection/leaderboard',
    'text!template/leaderboard.html'
    ],
    function($, _, Backbone, Router, LeaderboardCollection, LeaderboardTemplate) {

        var LeaderboardView = Backbone.View.extend({
            el: '#leaderboard',
            template: _.template(LeaderboardTemplate),
            initialize: function(){
                var self = this;
                self.collection = new LeaderboardCollection();
                self.collection.fetch({
                    success: function(collection, response, options){
                        self.$el.html(self.template({ players: collection.toJSON()}));
                    }
                })              

            }
        });

        return LeaderboardView;
});
```

Which renders correctly.  As the fetch call is asynchronous i assume that calling the template render after the fetch does not account for the data actually being there.  Further research suggests that this is not the way to populate a view on page load but to bootstrap it instead